# Implement an auto-resizing mechanism of editors

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, monaco-editor, react-lifecycle, react-ref

I would like to implement a resizing mechanism for `Editor 2`:

- The main purpose is to let the height of `Editor 2` auto-resize so as to occupy the rest of the page after adding/removing `Editor 1` and each resizing of the window.
- In the beginning, there is only `Editor 2` in the window. `Click to toggle "Editor 1"` allows to add or remove `Editor 1`.
- The height of `Editor 1` is implemented by `calculateNextHeightFirst`. It has minimum 3 rows, then is determined by the height of the content, but has maximum 10 rows.
- After adding `Editor 1`, the resizing of `Editor 2` needs to be triggered to occupy the rest of the page.
- Resizing `Editor 1` by adding or removing contents does not need to systematically trigger the resizing of `Editor 2`. It's especially the resizing of the window that triggers the resizing of `Editor 2`.

Here is my current code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-5nkshr?file=EditorBasic.tsx,App.tsx,EditorPlus.tsx,index.html

The behaviour of the code satisfies my requirement described above. However, at least one thing I find not normal is, I need to manually set `height: 72` as initial state of `EditorPlus`, which is same as the initial height of `Editor 1` determined by `calculateNextHeightFirst`. Otherwise, after clicking `Click to toggle "Editor 1"`, `this.aRef.current.clientHeight` would not be correctly set, thus the height of `Editor 2` would not be well set.

Maybe I would need rare lifecycle methods such as `getDerivedStateFromProps`, does anyone confirm?

As this case involves event handlers, react Refs, React lifecycle, and editors, could anyone tell me if my code is properly implemented?

(* link in codereview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/282577 *)